# Reading url from file Python

Tags: python, readfile

can not read the url in txt file
I want to read and open the url addresses in txt one by one, and I want to get the title of the title with regex from the source of url addresses
Error messages:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Mypy.py", line 14, in
>   
>       UrlsOpen = urllib2.urlopen(listSplit)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 420, in open
>       req.timeout = timeout AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Mypy.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import requests
import urllib2
import threading

UrlListFile = open("Url.txt","r") 
UrlListRead = UrlListFile.read() 
UrlListFile.close() 
listSplit = UrlListRead.split('\r\n')


    UrlsOpen = urllib2.urlopen(listSplit)
    ReadSource = UrlsOpen.read().decode('utf-8')
    regex = '<title.*?>(.+?)</title>'
    comp = re.compile(regex)
    links = re.findall(comp,ReadSource)
    for i in links:
        SaveDataFiles = open("SaveDataMyFile.txt","w")
        SaveDataFiles.write(i)
    SaveDataFiles.close()
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your `Url.txt` content ?

Comment: @fievel My Url.txt https://i.stack.imgur.com/s81Mt.png

Comment: Can you copy the contents of your URL.txt file and paste it in your question using code formatting? It will make out a lot easier to help you debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling `urllib2.urlopen(listSplit)` listSplit is a list when it needs to be a [string or request object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). It's a simple fix to iterate over the listSplit instead of passing the entire list to urlopen.

Also `re.findall()` will return a list for each ReadSource searched. You can handle this a couple of ways:

I chose to handle it by just making a list of lists

`websites = [ [link, link], [link], [link, link, link]`

and iterating over both lists. This makes it so you can do something specific for each list of urls from each website (put in different file ect...).

You could also flatten the `website` list to just contain the links instead of another list that then contains the links:

`links = [link, link, link, link]`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import urllib2
from pprint import pprint

UrlListFile = open("Url.txt", "r")
UrlListRead = UrlListFile.read()
UrlListFile.close()
listSplit = UrlListRead.splitlines()
pprint(listSplit)
regex = '<title.*?>(.+?)</title>'
comp = re.compile(regex)
websites = []
for url in listSplit:
    UrlsOpen = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    ReadSource = UrlsOpen.read().decode('utf-8')
    websites.append(re.findall(comp, ReadSource))

with open("SaveDataMyFile.txt", "w") as SaveDataFiles:
    for website in websites:
        for link in website:
            pprint(link)
            SaveDataFiles.write(link.encode('utf-8'))
    SaveDataFiles.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Mypy.py", line 14, in <module>
   UrlsOpen = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
   return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 427, in open
   req = meth(req)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1126, in do_request_
   raise URLError('no host given')
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>

Comment: I updated the code to work with more new links `.splitlines()` and to fix an encoding error `link.encode('utf-8')`. Give the new code a try.